# Fetch Data with interval in javascript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pusher, pusher-js

i have the following code with Pusher:

```
Echo.private("channel").listen(".foobar", (e) => {
   this.fetchData();
});
```

When there is an incoming request, I want data to be fetched again. But not on every Pusher event. I want the data to be fetched only once in 5 seconds.

I was thinking about a interval that is reset when there is a new incoming event, but how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first of all it's a `Laravel Echo` code. It may be using pusher behind the scenes, but saying it's a pusher code is slightly incorrect.

Then, if I understand you right, you need some kind of **debounce** function. For example `lodash` [offers one](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce).

```js
const debouncedFunction = _.debounce(() => {
    this.fetchData()
}, 5000);

Echo.private('channel').listen('.foobar', e => {
   debounced()
})
```

`debounce` will create debounced version of function which you can then call, or even cancel, because it comes with `cancel` method.

```js
debouncedFunction.cancel()
```